# How to get the DIV before the closest one

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you hover over the `My` text the `myicon.png` fades out and then back in:

```
<div class="mmItemStyleChild">
    <img src="theImages/myicon.png" class="mIcon vertAlign mmm1" id="mMW1" /> <img src="theImages/emptyImg.png" class="mSpacerStyle" /><span id="mMW" class="vertAlign mmm">My</span>
</div>

$('.mmm').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').first().stop().animate({ 'opacity': .35 });
}, function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').first().stop().animate({ 'opacity': 1 });
});
```

I was trying to do the same for the below but it isn't working:

```
<div class="mBtnMidS mBtnMidStyle">
    <div>
        <img id="mbS1" src="theImages/services_icon.png" class="mBtnIcon" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="mbS" class="mbBtnText">Services</span>
    </div>
</div>

$('.mbBtnText').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').first().stop().animate({ 'opacity': .55 });
}, function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').first().stop().animate({ 'opacity': 1 });
});
```

How can I modify the above code so it looks from the parent DIV (either using class 'mBtnMidS` or 'mBtnMidStyle') and gets the image and does the same fade animation as the first script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code block change:

```
$(this).closest('div')
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('div.mBtnMidS.mBtnMidStyle')
```

The way you had it, the closest div was the parent div of the span, but you wanted that div's parent (the span's grandparent div).